# Assigning subobject

Tags: c++

What is the proper way to assign a subobject? For example:

```
struct A {
  int x = 2;
  int y = 3;
};

struct B: A {
  int z = 5;
};

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<B> bp{new B{}};
  A a;
  a.x = 12;
  a.y = 13;
  *(static_cast<A*>(bp.get())) = a; // happens to work, but is it the right way?
  std::cout << bp->x << " " << bp->y << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This works (or happens to work?), but is awkward and relies on an assumption about the layout of `B`. So, what is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be slightly more idiomatic:

```
bp->A::operator=(a);
```

This kind of thing is pretty rare though, so it is hard to say.  In general, the more you can avoid casts the better, but having an explicit cast may be useful in this case to make it clear you are doing something unusual.

Comment: Why is it so unusual? Also, is explicit cast guaranteed to work in this case?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Hard to say exactly why, but in my experience it is unusual.  Generally if you are using inheritance you are also trying to do some kind of abstraction of the object state.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: The use of x,y,z members makes me think it is trying to model Cartesian coordinates.  By using inheritance, you are effectively saying that a 3D coordinate is a 2D coordinate, which isn't the right model.  Maybe that wasn't the intent though.

Comment: No, that wasn't the intent. In my application, `B` is a search node of the A* search algorithm. `A` is the data traditionally stored with such a node. So, `x` and `y` stand for `g-` and `f-` values; `z` stands for the state corresponding to the node. I want to enable direct access to `g-` and `f-` values of a search node and that's why I do not use composition.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you don't assign subobjects. It's conceptually wrong and violates how inheritance is supposed to work. If you need this, perhaps you have the wrong abstraction and really want composition:

```
struct B {
    A a;
};

std::unique_ptr<B> bp{new B{}};
A a{12, 13};
bp->a = a;
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "it's conceptually wrong and violates how inheritance is supposed to work"?